# How do the 'frozen goods' survive the banana stand fire?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrested-development

In the season two episode "Spring Breakout" it is discovered that there were 250ccs of "frozen goods" stored in the freezer at the Blueth banana stand dating back to before the timeline of the TV show. However, in season one there was a fire that destroyed the banana stand and in season two there was a car drive over the banana stand, amongst other calamities.

How did the frozen goods survive the the banana stand being destroyed multiple times?

Comment: Maybe the cooler wasn't there the whole time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately for the finest-show-that-has-ever-aired-on-television, I believe these to be plot holes.

As stated in season two, an **annual** Christmas tradition by Newport Beach youths is to destroy the banana stand by throwing it into the ocean. Seeing as how this occurs *each year*, there is no rational explanation for "250 cc's of [Michael's] father" to be stored there, nor is it a prudent place to store $250,000 lined within its walls.

While it is true that both a drink cooler and (presumably) cellophane-wrapped quarter of a million dollars can withstand being dumped into the ocean, it definitely couldn't have survived a fire nor go unnoticed when run over and be rebuilt; it still seems more likely that it was a writing oversight than a calculated decision by Lucille and George Sr. to keep these things there.

....*then again*, how did Michael not look inside the decoy cooler before giving it away, too!?

Answer (score 2):

The frozen goods obviously could not survive.  It's absurd.  It's *intended* to be absurd.

*Arrested Development* consists entirely of absurd, unrealistic situations--that's the wellspring of its humor.  If any portion of the story ever turns out to be realistic, that would probably indicate a mistake on the writers' part.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense. Lucille was hiding it in a certain place and then transferred it to the banana stand after the fire...
It does makes sense to change where you stash valuable things every once in a while...

Also, "there's always money in the banana stand" might not be as literal as it sounds, but rather as a hint, like, "I recently hid money in case of an emergency."